# How is client side rendered app different from server side rendering in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an eCommerce website so SEO is absolutely important.I have only started with ReactJS development and since majority of the resources available use client side rendering, I ended up doing that.

I would like to know:

1. Is there much of a difference between React client side and server side rendered apps?
2. Is client side not optimized for SEO?
3. How much of extra effort it is to convert Client side rendered app to server side one?
4. What all components would actually be changed in process of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there much of a difference between React client side and server side rendered apps?

On the server you don't have DOM, so for example the `componentDidMount` will not be ran (because components are not actually mounted). Also you don't have access to `window`.

> Is client side not optimized for SEO?

Google behaves pretty good when it comes to rendering SPA apps, but the problem appear when you fetch data (for example text) from API. If the response is fast that content will be indexed, but if not, the crawler won't wait and the site will be indexed with blank spots.

> How much of extra effort it is to convert Client side rendered app to server side one?

It really depends on the complexity of the app.

> What all components would actually be changed in process of doing so?

No. The point is you actually render the same thing but not in the browser, but on the server. 
In the simplest case the only difference is that you use `ReactDOM.renderToString()` instead of `ReactDOM.render()`.

Comment: You're awesome :) Thank you!