# Does an isomorphic react app really add a "huge amount of complexity" to a regular client-side react app?

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I just read a post stating that universal/isomorphic react app "introduce a huge amount of complexity" (comparing to a regular client-side only react app). I have never tried isomorphic react and I am about to start a pretty complex app so I'm trying to decide whether i should go for isomorphic or not (SEO will be very important). I would be grateful to anyone that would be willing to share their experience with that, or could point me to some great post/tutorial that describe the challenges isomorphic react poses.

Also another question: is it a big job to turn a react client only app to an universal react app if ever I start with what I know but then decide to switch?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes it adds more complexity, but now there are plenty of boilerplate projects that can help you. e.g. https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example, https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit.

Comment: This is very wide topic, I would recommend you to read some universal/isomorphic tutorial first. That will give you some knowledge about complexity (which varies, depending on project). I've answered quite similar question recently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709298/how-is-client-side-rendered-app-different-from-server-side-rendering-in-reactjs/40709365#40709365), take a look, it may clarify some things.